# Passing jquery string to code in razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I was wondering how I could pass a string that I made with javascript into a code block in razor. Given the few lines of simple js below:

```
var k=0;
var str1 = 'Model.FeaturedItems[';
var str2 = '].SubHeadline.ToString();';
var query = str1 + k +str2;
```

How would I then pass the string query into a code block? something like this:

```
                   alert("@"+query);
```

should print the result of that line of code.
**EDIT:**
Basically I want to execute this code: `Model.FeaturedItems[0].SubHeadline.ToString();` and do something with the result in jquery. However I keep getting a syntax error trying the above.

Comment: What is your syntax error? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to achieve... The code in your razor view is executed on the server side when your page is rendered. But your javascript is executed on client side in your browser. So you cannot pass values from javascript to code in razor because they are execute in different times in different places.

Comment: The error is: """ is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javascript` works on client and `razor` on server, you trying execute client code on server. Just use `c#` in code blocks:

`C#` code:

```
@{
    int k = 0; 
    var query = Model.FeaturedItems[k].SubHeadline.ToString(); 
}
```

On client `@query` will contain some data, if it is in razor view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(@query); 
<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Main reason is that the JavaScript code runs on client-side and razor views are being rendered on server side. Create SubHeadlines array on client side [ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor : Initialize a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777385/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-initialize-a-javascript-array).