# How to convert List in c# to array in javascript and check the array item

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I have list in model and the item from database. I want put the item to array in java script. then when I put values in textbox and click the button the system check from the array the values have in array or not

when I try this code, its not work. Any ideas or suggestion?

**Model:**

```
public List<string> listponumber { get; set; }

public void getlist()
        {
            var listpo = new List<string>();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand cmdponumber = new SqlCommand("Select DISTINCT ponumber From t_transaction ORDER BY ponumber", connection);

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmdponumber.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                listpo.Add(rdr.GetString(0).ToString());
            }

            connection.Close();
            listponumber = new List<string>(listpo);
        }
```

**View:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btntest").click(function () {
            var ponumber = [@Model.listponumber]
            var txtvalues = document.getElementByID("textbox").value;
            if (ponumber.indexOf(txtvalues) > -1 ) {
                alert('Array');
            } else { 
              alert('not array');
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Might want to take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777385/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-initialize-a-javascript-array as it discusses essentially the same thing (though with dates instead of strings - but the concepts are the same)

Comment: @Tim thx for reply, I try it but not work, syntax error when I call it var activeDates = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ActiveDates));

Comment: If `listponumber` is the name of the property in your model, then it needs to be @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.listponumber))

Comment: @stephen yes, I use it, but when I close with ";" the syntax error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can convert the C# List into a Javascript array by using

```
<script>
    var javascriptArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ListToConvertToJavascript));
</script>
```

This will create a Json object with the data inside the List in your Model and you will be able to iterate through it in plain Javascript.

The syntax error might you get is the IDE telling you that you are using a syntax that the Javascript parser doesn't understand, which is the RAZR sentece @Html(...); you can ignore it.

Test it out using:

```
for(int i = 0; i < $(javascriptArray).lenght; i++){
    alert(javascriptArray[i]);
}
```

or opening your browser developer's console and typing the name of the array you are creating to see if it is populated by your Model List data.

Comment: Make sure to use the same name of the List in your model after in Json.Encode(Model.ListToConvertToJavascript)... where ListToConvertToJavascript is the name of your list: listponumber

Comment: @putra1908 javascript wants you to surround the @html.raw(...) part of the code in '' to treat it as a string, but doing like so you won't be able to iterate through ponumber as an array. It will then become a string and javascript would try to parse it as you try to use it.