# How to Assign JavaScript Variables Values to Server Side Variables in Razor View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
var STVal = "247";
var Name = "abc";
var Cat = "general";       
var temp = '@string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", Cat, Name, STVal);'

alert(temp);
```

STVal, Name, Cat are my JavaScript variables and I want to format the string and to pass these variables in Razor View.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777385/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-initialize-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for but I use this

```
var temp = "CAT-NAME-STVAL".replace('CAT',Cat).replace('NAME',Name).replace('STVAL',STVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Ajax call to a controller function with your parameter individually like

```
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
  url: "Controller/ActionMethod",  
  data: "{ STVal: '247', Name : 'abc', Cat : 'general' }",  
  dataType: "json",  
  success: function(response) { alert("item added"); },  
  error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.responseText); }
```

});

Receive the values in the Action Method and pass to a view like,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionMethod(string STVal, string Name, string Cat )
{
   // your code
   return view();
}
```